# undefined local variable or method `listings' in JS method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I had a JS view called index.js. However, I wanted to take the code index.js code and make it into a JS helper. I put this code into an AfterSearchSubmit() method.  However, I get the below error. How do I fix this?

index.js

```
(function(){
  var html = "<%= j(render(:partial => 'search/searchresults.html.erb', :locals=>{:listings => @listings})) %>"
    $('#listings').html(html);

})();
```

Which I want to convert to a JS Helper...

Assets/javascript/search_form.js

```
  AfterSearchSubmit(mylistings){
    var html = "<%= j(render(:partial => 'search/searchresults.html.erb', :locals=>{:listings => mylistings})) %>"
    $('#listings').html(html);
  }
```

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {Helpers.SearchForm.AfterSearchSubmit(@listings)}
en
```

error:
undefined local variable or method `listings' for #<#:0x00007f84ffc2f6b0>